# SqlServerCompact 4.0 cannot use all features of entity framework in WPF App

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework-6

I am using `EntityFramework.SQLServerCompact` nuget package in my WPF app.

It does work partially, e.g:

It does run `ToList()`.

It doesn't run `Where()` query and it show this exception:

> SqlCeException: The specified argument value for the function is not
>   valid. [ Argument # = 3,Name of function(if known) = case ]

When I run this following query:

```
_db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == email_input.Text.ToString() && x.Password == password_input.Password.ToString())
```

The query which it runs is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt]
    FROM [Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Email] = (CASE WHEN (cast(@p__linq__0 as ntext) IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE @p__linq__0 END)) AND ([Extent1].[Password] = (CASE WHEN (cast(@p__linq__1 as ntext) IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE @p__linq__1 END))
```

Comment: I would try casting the two variables to string outside the linq. See if that makes it realise they can't be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `ToString()` in the predicate. Try to allocate the strings before you construct the query:

```
string email = email_input.Text.ToString(); //isn't Text already a string by the way?
string pwd = password_input.Password.ToString();

var users = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == pwd).ToArray();
```

Note that SQL Server Compact Edition has been deprecated.